# rails, how to know when to send out an email on DEF CREATE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
  def create

    @permission = @project.permissions.create(params[:permission])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @permission.save
        format.js
      else
        format.js   { render :js => @permission.errors }
      end
    end
  end
```

I want to add in a Mailer, to let the user know they have been added to a project, the issue is, if I pu that before the respond_to, the record hasn't been saved yet so it's possible that something could go wrong but the user would still get an email.

```
 UserMailer.xxxxxxxxx_notification(objecthere).deliver
```

And I'm guessing I can't put a mailer inside the respond_to block. Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what **observers** are used for.

create `app/models/permission_observer.rb`

```
class PermissionObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(permission)
    # put your mailer code here
  end
end
```

in `config/application.rb` add the observer

```
config.active_record.observers = :permission_observer
```

You can read more about observers [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers).

Also, you should be using `@project.permissions.new` instead of create. create saves the model immediately, making your `@permission.save` call redundant.

Once you have this in place, you should look into making your mailer code asynchronous so it doesn't hold up web requests. [Here's an example](http://wekeroad.tumblr.com/post/1650146551/asynchronous-email-with-actionmailer-and-delayed-job) using delayed_job.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can edit your code to:

```
def create
  @permission = @project.permissions.build(params[:permission])

  if @permission.save
    UserMailer.xxxxxxxxx_notification(objecthere).deliver
    respond_to do |format|  
      format.js
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js   { render :js => @permission.errors }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put a callback in your Permission model:

```
class Permission
  after_create :send_mail

  def send_mail
    UserMailer.xxxxxxxxx_notification(self).deliver
  end
end
```